# ServerAlias Exceptions

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, serveralias

I am looking for a special configuration for Apache (and eventually NGinx) to allow to map **all** but one host as a ServerAlias to a specific VHost configuration.

For example, my current setting is:

```
  ServerAlias *.dertermin.com
```

Basically catching all subdomains of determin.com and routing them to the docroot. However, I want a specific hostname eg. prerelease.dertermin.com to point to another docroot. Yet creating a separate VHost entry does not work. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your more specific prerelease rule is above the catchall rule as the Apache configuration is processed.

Apaches conf.d directory is processed in lexographic order.

Comment: I have tried this as the very first thing ;-) unfortunately this does not help :(

Comment: @clops Should work.. what output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?